# wcf service stop responding i think it because the application is not closing connactions to wcf

Tags: wcf

this is not my wcf service but i would like to fix it 
i need second opinion
here is the code of opening the service from silverlight
i can not put all the code because the project is very big
i just do not see in all the project a m_MdxService.close()
 and i think problem off randomly the wcf stop responding
and the only thing fixing it is recycling appication pool 
is because  the silverlight is not closing the wcf object .
the wcf service is running on it own application pool . the server is 64 bit

```
 public abstract class CubeControl : Control, IFilter
    {
            protected MdxClient m_MdxService;
            protected GeneralClient m_GeneralService;
            protected PortalClient m_PortalService;
            protected ListsSoapClient m_PortalListsService;

     public GraphControl(string cubeName, SharedContract.Filters filter)
            : base(cubeName) 
        {
            AttachEvents();
            Init(filter); 
        }

 public override void UpdateGraph()
        {
            flipable.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            progressStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            noDataStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            DataPointEventArgs dpe;

            switch (m_DrillLevel)
            {
                case 0:
                    m_MdxService.GetGraphDataAsync(SharedContract.Enums.Query.NumberOfEmployees, Filter, null, null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    dpe = m_DrillParam as DataPointEventArgs;
                     m_MdxService.GetGraphDataAsync(SharedContract.Enums.Query.NumberOfEmployeesYears, Filter, dpe.Key, null);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dpe = m_DrillParam as DataPointEventArgs;
                    string temp = selectedYear + "," + dpe.Key.ToString();
                    m_MdxService.GetGraphDataAsync(SharedContract.Enums.Query.NumberOfEmployeesMonth, Filter, temp, null);
                    break;
            }
        }
     void InitServices()
            {
                m_MdxService = new MdxClient();

                m_MdxService.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 0);

                m_GeneralService = new GeneralClient();

                m_GeneralService.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 0);

                m_PortalService = new PortalClient();

                m_PortalService.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 0);

                m_PortalListsService = new ListsSoapClient();

                m_PortalListsService.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 0);
            }


      void AttachEvents()
            {
                m_MdxService.GetGraphDataCompleted += new               EventHandler<GetGraphDataCompletedEventArgs>(m_MdxService_GetGraphDataCompleted);
            }

            void m_MdxService_GetGraphDataCompleted(object sender, GetGraphDataCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                GetGraphDataCompleted(sender, e);

                GetDataCompleted(this);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the client withing the control why not have a central access and creating point for the service proxy withing your silverlight client.

Eg. On the application class of your silverlight app add a member MdxService of type "proxy". Then at application startup time configure the binding and endpoint and create the instance.

Then within your control access it using App.Current.MdxService.GetGraphDataAsync also register for the completed event with App.Current.MdxService..GetGraphDataCompleted.

That way you have one instance of your service client.

I do however think that your issue runs deeper and you need to find the root cause.If the application pool needs recycling there definitely some other cause in my mind. Have a look at the size of your workingset on the server hosting the service. It might be that api has causing memory issues. If its around 900MB and appPool is running in 32bit mode you have a problem on server if 64bit mode it will be able to handle much more tho.

maybe think about running that service separately. In its own application pool and compile and deploy it separately.

Hope helps
Cheers

Comment: the service is running on it own application pool . the server is 64 bit

Comment: ok.What is do you know the size of the payload you sending back to the client? What happens when you do an IIS reset as I found recycling the appPool doesnt do much for working set size.

Comment: in this question i just want to know if this code above can Cause the problem